# SQL DataSource using WHERE IN clause

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sqldatasource, where-in

Using Studio 2010 C# with DB2 UDB 9.7.5

I have a gridview being populated from a DataSource with a WHERE IN clause as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="LUWAccts" runat="server" onSelecting="gvGrid01_Selecting"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LUWHAConnect %>" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LUWHAConnect.ProviderName %>" 

SelectCommand="SELECT mycolumns FROM mytables WHERE GROUP_NAME IN ? ">
<SelectParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="grpList" Type="String" /> 
</SelectParameters>
```

Hardcoding the WHERE clause works fine 
(i.e. WHERE GROUP_NAME IN ('GROUP1','GROUP2','GROUP3')

But I am trying to build the group list using the onSelecting event of my data source in my code behind as follows:

```
protected void gvGrid01_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
  string gpList = Get_SVCACCT_Auth_Groups(Session["ThisUser"].ToString());
              //This routine returns the string "('GROUP1','GROUP2','GROUP3')"
}
```

When I display the grpList string I do in fact have ('GROUP1','GROUP2','GROUP3').

But I do not get any data displayed.  I've searched and tried various techniques to alter the SELECT statement, modify the parm list using e.Command.Parameters.Add, using ControlParemeters, etc.

I also read a post about how WHERE IN clauses cannot handle comma-separated lists paremeters, but the IN keyword can query against a table.

My gpList is not built from another SELECT statement - but I still tried a few examples of this with no luck.  Being a novice - I seem to be dancing around the solution.

Please let me know if I've missed a post that would help answer this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried running the Select query inside of C# / SQL Server..? if so are you passing values as Double Quoted Values or Single Quoted Values..?can you pass it in as a String {0} param like this 
"SELECT mycolumns FROM mytables WHERE GROUP_NAME IN {0}" in code behind  pass in the param using stringFormat() perhaps

Comment: Changing the where clause to WHERE GROUP_NAME IN {0} gives me an Invalid SQL Syntax error.  What would need to change in my <SelectParameters> ?

Comment: Select Parameters what are they set at currently..?

Comment: <asp:Parameter Name="grpList" Type="String" /> In the onSelecting event the string grpList is "'GROUP1','GROUP2','GROUP3'" (comma-separated group names with single quotes). I am passing the value back to my datasource with e.Command.Parameters["@grpList"].Value = mygrouplist;

Comment: then that should work since you already have the values

Comment: I got part of the way there. I changed the WHERE clause to `WHERE GROUP_NAME IN @authGrps` and I removed quotes from my data values so that e.Command.Parameters["@grpList"].Value = GROUP1. With this the sql returns data for GROUP1.  But adding another group to the list GROUP1,GROUP2,etc. does not produce results.

Comment: VisDev's answer is what I was trying to get you to do the first time..btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your gvGrid01_Selecting event

```
LUWAccts.SelectCommand = 
String.Format("SELECT mycolumns FROM mytables WHERE GROUP_NAME IN {0})",
Get_SVCACCT_Auth_Groups(Session["ThisUser"].ToString()));
```

[Check this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1553050.aspx)

Comment: Formatting the select command worked great - displaying LUWAccts.SelectCommand.ToString() gives me `SELECT mycolumns FROM mytables WHERE GROUP_NAME IN ('GROUP1','GROUP2')` But still no results. I assume from these examples there are no <SelectParameters> in play here - correct? Or should I also be passing back Command.Parameters here?

Comment: In the same event, add 'gvGrid01.DataBind();'. Whenever you are changing the data source - (in your case the select command) you have to rebind the grid view.

Comment: putting the databind in the Selecting event gives me an endless loop

Comment: However - I moved all the logic discussed above into gvGrid01.Databind() and stopped using the SqlDataSource OnSelecting event. It all worked. Does this sound like a fair solution or could this present any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Decided to use Like and joining them with OR. So i do iterate on list of items and add like filter and attach them with or something like this:

```
string[] allStr = recieveFilter.Split(',');
string filterRecieverItem = "";
foreach (string recieveItem in allStr)
{
   filterRecieverItem += "(sampleField like '%" + recieveItem.Trim() + "%') OR ";
}
filterRecieverItem = filterRecieverItem.Remove(filterRecieverItem.Length - 3, 3);
ds_Sample.FilterExpression = filterStr;
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest you do something like by user VisDev
String.Format("SELECT mycolumns FROM mytables WHERE GROUP_NAME IN ({0})", yourparamlist)

Where yourparamlist would be

"value1, value2, value3"
its just a hint so you can implement it according to your requirement.

Hope it will solve your problem.